# Is there any support for implement Stripe payment gateway with valid OTP or other verification in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, stripe-payments, flutter-dependencies, flutter-devtools

1. I want to implement a Stripe payment gateway using verification. Sometimes users' banks send them OTP for security reasons and also for verification.
2. I can't find any solutions for that.

Answer (score 1):

Use [flutter_stripe](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_stripe) if user card is 3d secure call **`handleCardAction`** method provide by stripe SDKs which accept **`payment_intent_client_secret`**
this method automatically redirect to bank verification page .
after verification it return status now you can handle your own view according to status.

```
final paymentIntent=    await Stripe.instance.handleCardAction(
                        'payment_intent_client_secret');
  switch (paymentIntent.status) {
                case PaymentIntentsStatus.Succeeded:
                      // TODO: Handle this case.
                  break;
                case PaymentIntentsStatus.RequiresPaymentMethod:
                  // TODO: Handle this case.
                  break;
                case PaymentIntentsStatus.RequiresConfirmation:
                  // TODO: Handle this case.
                  break;
                case PaymentIntentsStatus.RequiresAction:
                  // TODO: Handle this case.
                  break;
                case PaymentIntentsStatus.RequiresCapture:
                  // TODO: Handle this case.
                  break;
                case PaymentIntentsStatus.Unknown:
                  // TODO: Handle this case.
                  break;
                case PaymentIntentsStatus.Canceled:
                  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                      content: Text("Payment Cancelled")));
                  break;
                case PaymentIntentsStatus.Processing:
                  // TODO: Handle this case.
                  break;
              }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use flutter strip SDK for integrate stripe payment with many other functionalities.  [flutter_stripe](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_stripe)

Comment: Can I verify OTP in this?

Comment: no, you can't but flutter is open source so if you need to change the library than you can do it. but I think for only verifying mobile numbers no need to change library. please give me a full description of exactly what you want so I can give you proper flow.

Comment: I want to implement stripe in the flutter.
In some cases, the user's bank verifies the payment via OTP at that time how does it all work?
I don't have flow for that.

Comment: @VimeshPatel you can check my answer if you are using same package `flutter_stripe` it will be work